# Postgresql json functions missing

Tags: postgresql

it seems like my postgres doesn't have the json functions.

```
to_json('Fred said "Hi."'::text)
```

generates:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_json"
LINE 1: to_json('Fred said "Hi."'::text)
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Any idea on how to enable or get the functions to work? Thought they where supposed to be there out of the box.

Comment: ` select to_json('Fred said "Hi."'::text);` working?

Comment: did you try casting the text to json? e.g. `SELECT  '{"key": "value"}'::json;`

Comment: Read the error message.  It says "syntax error", not "function...does not exist".  In SQL, you don't invoke functions just by blurting our their names in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had misunderstood the syntas - it should include `SELECT`, so `SELECT to_json('Fred said "Hi."'::text)`works.